# Cannot move out of borrowed content when borrowing a generic type

Tags: pointers, rust

I have a program that more or less looks like this

```
struct Test<T> {
    vec: Vec<T>
}

impl<T> Test<T> {
    fn get_first(&self) -> &T {
        &self.vec[0]
    }

    fn do_something_with_x(&self, x: T) {
        // Irrelevant
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t = Test { vec: vec![1i32, 2, 3] };
    let x = t.get_first();
    t.do_something_with_x(*x);
}
```

Basically, we call a method on the struct `Test` that borrows some value. Then we call another method on the same struct, passing the previously obtained value.

This example works perfectly fine. Now, when we make the content of `main` generic, it doesn't work anymore.

```
fn generic_main<T>(t: Test<T>) {
    let x = t.get_first();
    t.do_something_with_x(*x);
}
```

Then I get the following error:

> error: cannot move out of borrowed content
>
> src/main.rs:14         let raw_x = *x;

I'm not completely sure why this is happening. Can someone explain to me why `Test<i32>` isn't borrowed when calling `get_first` while `Test<T>` is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is that `i32` implements the `Copy` trait, but `T` does not. If you use `fn generic_main<T: Copy>(t: Test<T>)`, then your immediate problem is fixed.

The longer answer is that `Copy` is a special trait which means values can be copied by simply copying bits. Types like `i32` implement `Copy`. Types like `String` do *not* implement `Copy` because, for example, it requires a heap allocation. If you copied a `String` just by copying bits, you'd end up with two `String` values pointing to the same chunk of memory. That would not be good (it's unsafe!).

Therefore, giving your `T` a `Copy` bound is quite restrictive. A less restrictive bound would be `T: Clone`. The `Clone` trait is similar to `Copy` (in that it copies values), but it's usually done by more than just "copying bits." For example, the `String` type will implement `Clone` by creating a new heap allocation for the underlying memory.

This requires you to change how your `generic_main` is written:

```
fn generic_main<T: Clone>(t: Test<T>) {
    let x = t.get_first();
    t.do_something_with_x(x.clone());
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to have either the `Clone` or `Copy` bounds, then you could change your `do_something_with_x` method to take a *reference* to `T` rather than an owned `T`:

```
impl<T> Test<T> {
    // other methods elided

    fn do_something_with_x(&self, x: &T) {
        // Irrelevant
    }
}
```

And your `generic_main` stays mostly the same, except you don't dereference `x`:

```
fn generic_main<T>(t: Test<T>) {
    let x = t.get_first();
    t.do_something_with_x(x);
}
```

You can read more about `Copy` [in the docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). There are some nice examples, including how to implement `Copy` for your own types.

Comment: The use of "moving bits" is a bit confusing, as Rust moves by moving bits. Maybe "copying bits" would be clearer?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Sure. Updated. For what it's worth, I took the previous wording straight from the language reference: 'Copy, for "Plain Old Data" types which can be copied by simply moving bits.'

Comment: @BurntSushi5: Interesting, maybe we should warn steve than using "move" in the context of "copy" is a bit confusing?