# Moving collection out of context

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to implement some traits using life times but as per usual I'm fighting the borrow checker.

My trait looks like this:

```
pub struct Matrix<T> {
    pub cols: usize,
    pub rows: usize,
    pub data: Vec<T>
}

impl<'a, 'b, T: Copy + Mul<T, Output=T>> Mul<&'b T> for &'a Matrix<T> {
    type Output = Matrix<T>;

    fn mul(self, f: &T) -> Matrix<T> {
        let new_data : Vec<T> = self.data.into_iter().map(|v| v * (*f)).collect();

        Matrix {
            cols: self.cols,
            rows: self.rows,
            data: new_data
        }
    }
}
```

Playground [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b215a84e4381a440fa7c&version=stable)

This gives the following error:

```
error: cannot move out of borrowed content
```

I think I understand why this is happening: I am borrowing self and so I can't copy the data. How do I get around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot move out of borrowed content when borrowing a generic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595075/cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content-when-borrowing-a-generic-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are using `into_iter()` on the vector. Since you have `Copy` bound on `T`, this is unnecessary; you can use just `iter()` and dereference the argument in the closure:

```
pub struct Matrix<T> {
    pub cols: usize,
    pub rows: usize,
    pub data: Vec<T>
}

impl<'a, 'b, T: Copy + Mul<T, Output=T>> Mul<&'b T> for &'a Matrix<T> {
    type Output = Matrix<T>;

    fn mul(self, f: &T) -> Matrix<T> {
        let new_data: Vec<T> = self.data.iter().map(|v| *v * *f).collect();

        Matrix {
            cols: self.cols,
            rows: self.rows,
            data: new_data
        }
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=da1dff5374ff9b62275e&version=stable))

Comment: And the important thing about `into_iter` is that [it *consumes* the `self` argument](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#tymethod.into_iter): `fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter`. `iter`, on the other hand, only [requires a reference](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) (`&self`).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I knew it had to be something simple!